# running 'sbt new' noninteractively

Tags: scala, sbt, giter8

[sbt new](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/sbt-new-and-Templates.html#Trying+new+command) by default prompts the user to fill in various values.

Is there a way to accept the defaults noninteractively, or specify values on the command-line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can pass parameters with flags. For instance this is how to call the [scalafix template](https://github.com/scalacenter/scalafix.g8) non-interactively.

```
sbt new scalacenter/scalafix.g8 --rewrite="reponame" --version="v1.0"
```